Referencing Table of a Single BU When Using a Multi-BU Marketing Cloud Instance
Summary:  My reference of the child BU's synchronized table is not being recognized.
I am working in a Marketing Cloud instance that has two business units, each with their own Salesforce instances that have synchronized tables in their respective BUs in MC.  No shared tables.  Everything, including SQL queries, are kept separate.  Nothing is being shared or cross-referenced across BUs (except, of course, the All Subscribers table which I understand is auto-populated by MC).
NOTE:  I am assuming that the first BU that is added (the one that has "1st Org" listed after its name) is the one considered to be the parent.
The child BU's synchronized table from its Salesforce instance is "Leads_Salesforce".
The parent BU's synchronized table from its Salesforce instance is "Leads_Salesforce_1"
When I created a SQL Query in the parent's BU, I referenced "Lead_Salesforce_1", and it was recognized as a table.  But when I created a SQL Query in the child's BU, I referenced "Lead_Salesforce", and it was not recognized as a table.
Because I am in a multi-BU MC instance, do I need to change how I reference the child's tables?

Have you tried using the prefix "ENT." before the synchronized data extension name? i.e., ENT.Lead_Salesforce.
This prefix can be used if you want to query from the child Business Unit level

Thank you for offering your help!  Yes, I had, but I tried it again just in case and still got this error.  "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The [ENT.Lead_Salesforce] table has a multi-part specification. This is not allowed.
[ENT.Lead_Salesforce] is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views."  Is it possible that the person that joined the Salesforce instances into two different BUs in MC did so as EQUAL BUs instead of Parent/Child?  Or is that not possible within MC?

Try moving the square brackets so it doesn't include the ent., i.e., ENT.[Lead_Salesforce]. Having the whole thing incased in a [ ... ] would cause the error message you have sent.

THAT WORKED!  Thank you very much for your help!  Why/How does the placement of the brackets change how its interpreted?

Great, that's good to hear. The square brackets are used if you have keywords or special chars in the column names or identifiers. Having 'ENT.' inside the brackets would result in this losing its effect and simply becoming part of the data extension name. This means it would search locally for a data extension called 'ENT.Lead_Salesforce' instead of across business units for 'Lead_Salesforce'.

I realized I forgot to respond after you explained.  Thank you very much for the explanation!
